# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError using Spring and hibernate in glassfish

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, glassfish

I'm using spring(3.0.4.RELEASE) and hibernate (3.4.0.GA) and deploying into a glassfish (web_3.1) container.

I have 2 wars and I want them to share the same cache via JNDI (this is very important to me, I've already used terracotta but it is too heavy weight for our needs), so I've added the hibernate and ehcache jars to domains/domain1/lib/ext/

```
    antlr-2.7.6.jar        
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar         
    ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar       
    hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar  
    hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar  
    jta-1.1.jar       
    postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar  
    slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
    commons-collections-3.1.jar  
    ehcache-core-2.4.2.jar  
    hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar  
    hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar                
    javassist-3.4.GA.jar                  
    log4j-1.2.16.jar  
    slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar           
    xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

The spring libs and dependencies are being included in both wars using maven to manage dependencies.

```
    activation-1.1.jar       
    cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar             
    commons-validator-1.3.1.jar                 
    hsqldb-2.2.4.jar         
    jsp-api-2.2.jar               
    slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar                       
    spring-orm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    aopalliance-1.0.jar
    commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
    dwr-2.0.3.jar
    itext-2.1.7.jar
    jstl-1.2.jar
    spring-aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-oxm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    aspectjweaver-1.6.9.jar
    commons-codec-1.3.jar
    ehcache-core-2.2.0.jar
    itransact.jar
    jta-1.1.jar
    spring-asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-tx-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar
    commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
    ehcache-spring-annotations-1.1.3.jar
    jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar
    jtelnet-1.0.jar
    spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    bcmail-jdk14-138.jar
    commons-digester-1.7.jar
    eodsql-2.1.jar
    jasperreports-3.7.6.jar
    mail-1.4.3.jar
    spring-context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    spring-webmvc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    bcmail-jdk16-1.46.jar
    commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
    freemarker-2.3.17.jar
    jcommon-1.0.15.jar
    netty-3.2.5.Final.jar
    spring-context-support-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
    terracotta-toolkit-1.3-runtime-3.2.0.jar
    bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar
    commons-io-2.1.jar
    guava-r07.jar
    jdtcore-3.1.0.jar
    postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar
    spring-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    webappenhance-0.0.0.20.jar
    bcprov-jdk14-138.jar
    commons-lang-2.5.jar
    hornetq-core-2.2.7.Final.jar
    jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
    quartz-1.8.5.jar
    spring-expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
    bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar
    commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    hornetq-jms-2.2.7.Final.jar
    jms-1.1.jar
    README.txt
    spring-jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
    bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
    commons-pool-20030825.183949.jar
    hornetq-spring-integration-2.2.7.Final.jar
    js-1.7R2.jar
    satso-core.jar
    spring-jms-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    xstream-1.3.1.jar
```

When I deploy either of the wars I get the following exception:

```
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [core-application-context-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence does not implement the requested interface javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5328)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [core-application-context-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence does not implement the requested interface javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4690)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5305)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence does not implement the requested interface javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 53 more
```

I've scoured the web and most of the problems involve a clash between ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar and the javax.persistence.jar provided with the application server.

But I can't find any other javax.persistence.jar in the deployed wars or in any lib folders that are on my classpath. To double check that this error is not being caused by a duplicate classes on the classpath, I removed ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar from the lib/ext directory and got the following error:

```
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [core-application-context-jpa.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#104bc3' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#104bc3' defined in class path resource [core-application-context-jpa.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5328)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [core-application-context-jpa.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#104bc3' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#104bc3' defined in class path resource [core-application-context-jpa.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4690)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5305)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#104bc3' defined in class path resource [core-application-context-jpa.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
        ... 56 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
        ... 60 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1465)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1368)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
        ... 62 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 86 more
```

This leads me to assume that the previous error is not caused by duplicate javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider classes on the classpath. I've toyed with the idea that spring and hibernate were compiled with different versions of javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider but this theory seems incorrect as I'm using the version as stated on the maven repository site:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.0.4.RELEASE

but using spring-orm-3.1.0 does not fix the problem and I imagine if the documentation on the maven repository was incorrect, I would be finding a long more people with a similar problem.

Any helpful advice on how to resolve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: The way I am trying to share ehcache between 2 wars using JNDI does not work due to class loading issues. In particular the entities need to be in a common location. Those interested in doing so should check out: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268129/whats-the-best-way-to-share-business-object-instances-between-java-web-apps-usi) and the other suggestion [link](http://springtips.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-shared-parent-application-context.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GF + Hibernate + Spring = many bad memories (at least for me). What you could do is go to the GF admin page, then update tool, then choose the Hibernate framework. It will be installed. Of course, remove all the hibernate libraries you added. I remember doing something like this..

Cheers, Eugene.

Comment: That did solve the problem, however it is also possible to solve the problem by placing the required jars in domains/domain1/lib. it appears that putting the libs in domains/domain1/lib/ext was causing the classloader problems. Also by placing the libs in domains/domain1/lib, I am able to use any version of hibernate, whereas using the update tool forces me to use 3.5. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: while reading what you wrote , I remembered doing the same thing :). Sorry, it has been a while now since I touched GF. Glad it worked out.